# Rally Custom HTML - Filter on Milestones

Tags: javascript, rally

I'm creating a "Rally Custom HTML" board using this grouped grid example.
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/example/groupable-grid

I'm having trouble adding a filter for a specific Milestone.  I can get the code below to return user stories without a problem.  It has a generic filter on name.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grouped Grid Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('CustomGrid', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                launch: function() {
                    this.add({
                        xtype: 'rallygrid',
                        columnCfgs: [
                            'FormattedID',
                            'Name',
                            'ScheduleState',
                            'Milestones'
                        ],
                        context: this.getContext(),
                        features: [{
                            ftype: 'groupingsummary',
                            groupHeaderTpl: '{name} ({rows.length})'
                        }],
                        storeConfig: {
                            model: 'UserStory',
                            groupField: 'Project',
                            groupDir: 'ASC',
                            filters : [
                                {
                                    property : 'Name',
                                    operator : 'contains',
                                    value : ' ' 
                                }
                            ],
                            fetch: ['Project'],
                            getGroupString: function(record) {
                                var Project = record.get('Project');
                                return (Project && Project._refObjectName) || 'No Project';
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            Rally.launchApp('CustomGrid', {
              name: 'Custom Grid'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

When I try to change the filter to use "Milestones" it doesn't return any results.  I'm able to access the Milestones property display it as a column.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grouped Grid Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('CustomGrid', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                launch: function() {
                    this.add({
                        xtype: 'rallygrid',
                        columnCfgs: [
                            'FormattedID',
                            'Name',
                            'ScheduleState',
                            'Milestones'
                        ],
                        context: this.getContext(),
                        features: [{
                            ftype: 'groupingsummary',
                            groupHeaderTpl: '{name} ({rows.length})'
                        }],
                        storeConfig: {
                            model: 'UserStory',
                            groupField: 'Project',
                            groupDir: 'ASC',
                            filters : [
                                {
                                    property : 'Milestones',
                                    operator : 'contains',
                                    value : ' ' 
                                }
                            ],
                            fetch: ['Project'],
                            getGroupString: function(record) {
                                var Project = record.get('Project');
                                return (Project && Project._refObjectName) || 'No Project';
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            Rally.launchApp('CustomGrid', {
              name: 'Custom Grid'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the ObjectId of the milestone you're trying to filter by you can make a filter like this:

```
{
    property : 'Milestones',
    operator : 'contains',
    value : '/milestone/12345' 
}
```

Or, you can search by name as well:

```
{
    property : 'Milestones.Name',
    operator : 'contains',
    value : 'A Milestone' 
}
```

You can also just paste the url into your browser to test until you get the query right:

[https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?query=(Milestones contains /milestone/12345)](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?query=(Milestones%20contains%20/milestone/12345))

Comment: That's what I tried initially, but I can't get it to return any results when I switch from the "Name" property filter to the "Milestones" filter.  I was using the "value : '/milestone/12345' " method with the ID of the milestone I'm after.  I just tried the "Milestones.Name" property, but had the same results.  To rule out any typos or other spelling issues, I put in a blank space(" ") and an empty string ("") for the search values they also did not return results.

Comment: hmm.... i just tried both of the above again in my sub and i was able to get results for both.  are you sure that there are stories that match your milestone query within the project scope you are searching?

Comment: Thank you!  You just turned me on to the answer.  My solution was right, but the milestone has features tied to it. Not user stories.  All of the user stories I'm seeing are because they are tied to the feature.  So many issues are becoming clear now!